# Update lazy loaded module on the fly in production mode

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material

I have a form builder project built with angular 9. It contains basic fields such as text field, 
textarea and some custom components. It can control the label, placeholder and other custom properties. After selecting the required components and filling out properties, it creates a form.component.ts, form.component.scss, form.component.html and form.module.ts and then override the files in another project.

In dev mode when this is done, nodejs detects the change and recompiles the changes and I can see my changes on localhost:4200

In prod mode, the entire project is already built with form.chunk.js as a lazy loaded module.
How can I update this module in prod mode without rebuilding the entire project?